# warning: Matlab-style short-circuit operation performed for operator &

Tags: octave

Code:

```
if (round(xw(1))>2) & (round(xw(2))>2) & (round(xw(1))<h-1) & (round(xw(2))<w-1)
        W0 = img(round(xw(1))-2:round(xw(1))+2,round(xw(2))-2:round(xw(2))+2);
else
        NA=1;
        break
endif
```

`xw` is a column vector which contains the co-ordinates of a point.
`h` and `w` are the dimensions of an image.

I am using these lines of codes in **OCTAVE**

But when I run the function which contains these lines I get a warning

`warning: Matlab-style short-circuit operation performed for operator &`

Is it that in spite of using `&`, **octave** is performing `&&` operation?

I learnt that if I use `&&` then depending on the first statement is `True` or `False`, the next statements are evaluated.

So, is this what is happening when I get this warning? What is the solution to this problem then?

I want to check if all the statements are `True` and not just the first one.

Comment: “I want to check if all the statements are True and not just the first one.” Short-circuiting in this case means that, if the first comparison is false, it skips the other ones. Their value doesn’t matter because `false AND <anything>` is false. Whether there is short-circuiting or not, the complete condition verifies that all comparisons are true.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can safely avoid the warning by using `&&` operator instead.

The warning comes from the fact that [Matlab has a special handling](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) for `&` operators in this context:

> When you use the element-wise & and | operators in the context of an
>   if or while loop expression (and only in that context), they use
>   short-circuiting to evaluate expressions.

For reasons of compatibility, Octave detects this behaviour and emulates what Matlab does. Note that its completely safe to use `&&` also in Matlab since that is what is implicitly used anyways.

Comment: But why is such a warning raised?

Comment: As I wrote, implicitly turning `&` into `&&` in the context of if and loop expressions is specific to Matlab. If you look into Octave's documentation, `&` is regularly Element-by-Element boolean expression. If you don't want Matlab compatibility, turning that implicitly into ´&&` is highly irregular and definitely raise a warning as it does. Given that Matlab compatibility is probably a high priority for Octave, I personally find issuing a warning to be a good compromise between strictness and compatibility.

Comment: But when i am using the code

`if (epsilon_c < 0.05) && (NA==0) && (round(xk(1))>0) && (round(xk(2))>0) && (round(xk(1))<h) && (round(xk(2))<w)`

In this line I am checking if the value of x and y co-ordinates in `xk` is greater than 0 and less than the dimension of the image.

But my result isn't as expected because the vectors `xk` with negative value for x or y are also getting included.

Comment: Based on that code negative values for xk (1) and xk (2) wont pass - unless round does something funny

Comment: I tried doing `round(-229)` separately in **command window** and it's output was `-229`

Comment: I guess I have to discard the negative values separately then :(

Comment: Typical XY-Problem (http://xyproblem.info/). @Siladittya: I think you should explain what you are trying to do. So far jsalonen answered your initial question (& vs. &&)

Comment: @Siladittya feel free to open another question if required.

Comment: @Siladittya `round(-229)` should return `-229` waht else do you expect? if you want to clamp doubles into a given integer range this can be done with a variety of methods but you should open a separate question for this

Comment: What could possibly be the reason to warn the user for behavior that is exactly as expected? It’s not like the result of the condition changes if you apply short-circuiting or not. Note that short-circuiting only applies if the operands to `&` are scalar.

Answer (score 3):

Jsalonen's answer is correct but I would like to give an alternative solution, i.e: to turn off the warning. The reason is that in some cases the warning arises because your program is calling routines or programs made by others, often so many of them that it is extremely time-consuming to find all the places where the & operators occur. It is easier simply to turn off the warning typing this Octave's command line:

warning ("off", "Octave:possible-matlab-short-circuit-operator")